# PHP-React Verify Cryptographic Signature

Tags: php, reactjs, cryptography, bioinformatics

I am using this package in React Native for Biometric authentication: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics

It sends a public key to our PHP server and then a cryptographic signature in which we had verify against.

Is there any library we should be used to verify the public key against the cryptographic signature in PHP?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find an answer to this? I stumble upon the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: See the updated answer @kml

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

1. Save the `public key` in DB
2. On every biometric attempt this library will send `signature` and `payload` to PHP
3. Compare `signature` with the `public key`
4. Authenticate user on success as `openssl_verify` will return 0 or 1

Code for step 3 is

> openssl_verify(
> $payload,
> base64_decode($signrature_in_step_3),
> $public_key_saved_in_step_1,
> "RSA-SHA256"
> );

PS: Make sure the `public key` in step 1 is formatted correctly or else `openssl_verify` will throw an exception: see the following example to achieve the correct format before using `openssl_verify`

```
$public_key_saved_in_step_1 = openssl_pkey_get_public("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$publicKeyStringFromDB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
```

Comment: did you save the public key in the database as a string? and just reuse it as is?

Comment: is $public_key_saved_in_step_1 a string?

Comment: Yes public key is saved in database

Comment: public_key_saved_in_step_1 should have valid format elase openssl_verify will throw exception

Comment: thanks so much for your response man, may I ask, how this should be formatted for use in openssl_verify?

Comment: I'm very new to this Cryptography, so I hope not to be a bother lol

Comment: `RSA Public Key

-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`

Comment: suppose server has 1000 user and 600 users have public key how we can check and verify user ?