# How to verify a RSA signature generated from react native lib in php

Tags: php, react-native, cryptography, rsa

The [react native library for biometrics](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics) generates a base 64 signature that I want to verify with the public key RSA 2048 stored in the database as plain text (generated by the library as well) to authentificate the user with the correct public key.
Following Topaco's comment I noticed that the public key and signature are returned from the library as a single line string with no padding.

```
$publicKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_public(("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".$publicKey."\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"));
$verify = openssl_verify($message, base64_decode($signature), $publicKeyResource, "sha256withRSAEncryption" );
```

$verify is always returning 0

Example of Public Key after formatting:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyEQAmIthd0J7TdWGLt1X
Q3TdGhzoXVMiiENy9HDqlQKPImEwy4PEzJUr9JEZsWE4LarxsgkKnVZgiE+cNxSV
cE+zVBNaeb2hKxejrRVBpe9xgXb2agjrG7twuTKyBe+SeEIB1LRfwVHcKw7jSLle
ih4xhMHtZ6Q/crgzkBLH/EZ47stTv80EcFvreM7S+bfVfajE7qiuNHvPNaRtLEVh
iC4PTUqSfnuEb1xv3uC7mnIRNLTxfgbwUmzjjfnUlr+jxcWyb35JVCtgb3nsV/2H
G0TCSyNJ5X0tPfIDy7EfDjc9Mj9n+thPgTKCtbMXwPCQu7jLqI4AAubstJv3p3Uc
NQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Example of Signature for the message: "auth"

```
mglZm2RKmkBIR+cNkuOJwAjnJJUAoyUl4w5NnzJsAFxuyvRhlJ3RS1Jksvzn90lp6lRG8aBy0nbxyCR2CpOjCH3G4XuUThTpJ862CPp5OMI9t9Ne6+/w2YiLj0Raq6WAiNDqxzg1PKRzojLvVpZd9P1URpevkoG6cQnk+FzITtESDmGaPtIgMV9ON2rrtF7Occ1PblFjSwCfkm3To3R4QdBgiVSdLIjoJvdff2RzId2dlGZxxiKyLs5JK6oFppmls/TcfMVvffj/fBFW9HjIggpHz8KmJTSb1crepK9WxrkKMvMs2Qsbd5nzf/SwiXDfFaBMKXJ30/2e3TqQ3CFXiQ==
```

I found a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566270/php-react-verify-cryptographic-signature?rq=1) about the same library but their solution is the same one I used and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please check the data. Key and signature do not seem to match (PKCS#1 v1.5 padding assumed).

Comment: @Topaco I tried using openssl_pkey_get_public for the public key padding but still got the same result (code updated)

Comment: The data does not seem to be consistent. Also under Java the signature cannot be verified with the key you posted (using the parameters of the [react native libarary](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/rnbiometrics/ReactNativeBiometrics.java#L93)).

Comment: I also checked and reached the same conclusion as Topaco: the signature does not seem to have made using the private key that goes with the public key you posted, assuming PKCS#1 v1.5.

Comment: i checked similar solution but it is not working in my case always returns false or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem  was that I had a snippet of code that I had forgotten about that called the function that generates a new keys pair before the authentification(when I check if the device supports biometrics or not) so I was verifying a signature generated by the new key with the old key saved in the database. Thanks @Topaco and @President James K. Polk for confirming the inconsistency between the signature and public key